# Unable to Clear ASP.net Through JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm having problems clearing an ASP.net Textbox through JavaScript on the onclick event of an image.  I want to do it this way to avoid a postback.
The ID is txtName.

This is what I am trying

```
<img alt="clear" src="" height="20" width="20" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('<%# txtName.ClientID %>').value=\"\";"></img>
```

I even tried checking the value by:

```
<img alt="clear" src="" height="20" width="20" onclick="javascript:alert(document.getElementById('<%# txtName.ClientID %>'));"></img>
```

Each time I run this could I get a blank web page.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your image tag is not well formed.

`<img />` is self closing, it doesn't need an end tag `</img>`.

Your JS is wrong:

```
.value=\"\";"
```

Should be:

```
.value='';"
```

Finally, you're using the DataBinding syntax for your `txtName` field:

```
#txtName
```

Should be (Expression syntax):

```
=txtName
```

Here is the correct <`img />` tag in it's entirety:

```
<img alt="clear" src="your image here" height="20" width="20" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('<%= txtName.ClientID %>').value='';" />
```